# Как отслеживать изменения в параметрах объекта с записью истории изменений при парсинге?

Tags: алгоритм, парсер, объекты, логирование, любой-язык

Я с помощью парсера получаю список объектов в формате JSON или XML. Данные сохраняю в базу.

Мне нужно отслеживать изменения в объектах с сохранением истории изменений. Например, может измениться количество объектов (появятся новые, пропадут некоторые старые). У объекта может измениться набор параметров (добавление новых параметров, пропажа части старых). Я обновляю информацию с заданной периодичностью.

Существует ли какое-то готовое решение, чтобы я мог получать отчёт об изменениях, чтобы было видно, что изменилось между последовательными запусками парсера?

Comment: В смысле, вам что конкретно надо то? Найти разницу между двумя текстами?

Comment: разницу между двумя объектами

Comment: [Find and return JSON differences using newtonsoft in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24876082/312041)?